# Google maps markers toggling div with respect to id

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i have difficulty in toggling marker in google maps specifically i'm using gmaps.js to open and close div. On "click" function how would i toggle up div open and close. Below is an example interaction that suits me:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zbteFZbu8JKc.kxnGVlIRxhQI&hl=en

```
arraylist = {
    name: "Gunung Kinabalu",
    height: 4095,
    latitude: 6.07484,
    longitude: 116.562853,
    location: "Sabah",
    picture: "Gunung Kinabalu.jpg"
 },

map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 4.2062722,
        lng: 107.9405116,
        zoomControl : true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
            style : 'SMALL',
            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 10,
        panControl : false,
        streetViewControl : false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
     });

      for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
        map.addMarker({
          id : arrayList[i].name,
          lat: arrayList[i].lat,
          lng: arrayList[i].lng,
          title: arrayList[i].name,
          infoWindow: {
            content: arrayList[i].name
          },              
          details: {
             name:arrayList[i].name,
             pic:arrayList[i].pic,
             height:arrayList[i].height,
             loc:arrayList[i].loc,
          },
          mouseover: function(e){
            this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
          },
          mouseout: function(e){
             this.infoWindow.close(this.map, this);
          },
          click: function(e){
             //here the events to toggle div
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have sufficient points to comment, so answering here.

If I understood your question right, you wanted to toggle the `infoWindow` on `mouseover` and `mouseout` of a marker. Here is a working fiddle that shows the `infoWindow` when you hover over a marker, and closes it when you move out of it - http://jsfiddle.net/e52792j5/822/.

Your code has mostly errors in the variable names. You just have to change the variable name from `arraylist` to `arrayList`, and since it's an array it should be enclosed within `[]`. Also, the property key is `latitude` and `longtitude` in the `addMarker` function and not `lat` and `lng` respectively.

**EDIT:**

Here's the updated fiddle that toggles a `div` with the details of the marker clicked - http://jsfiddle.net/e52792j5/940/

The `arrayList` object within the for loop is not inherited by the click event handler, as the handler gets executed only after the for loop has finished executing. As mentioned in the comments, you'd have to use a closure to access the parent scope variables. To access the `arrayList` object inside the click handler, you can use a self-invoking anonymous function that binds the value of `i` with `e`. Something like this:

```
click: (function(e){
    return function () {
       alert(e.name);
    }
})(arrayList[i])
```

To toggle a `div` with the details of the marker clicked, a combination of CSS transitions and jQuery can be used.

**jQuery:**

```
click: (function(e){
    return function () {
        var result = "  <button>close</button><p>"+ e.name +"</p><p>" + e.latitude+"  </p><p>"+ e.longitude+ "</p>";
        $("#toggleDetails").html(result);
        $("#toggleDetails").addClass("active"); 
    }
})(arrayList[i])
```

**CSS:**

```
#toggleDetails {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -150px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease; 
}

#toggleDetails.active {
  left: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm so sorry, and thank for correcting me about array. Dont mind about mousehover  and mouseout, its working well in my local. What i'm trying to do is onclick function. Whenever user click a marker then a div will open same as: 
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zbteFZbu8JKc.kxnGVlIRxhQI&hl=en. And when i click other region the div will closed back.

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated my answer based on your question. Hope that answers your question.